# C: Vectorize For Loops

Tags: c, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

A critical part of my code has the following two loops. The first one is to multiply complex vector `B` (dimensions: N) with complex matrix `out1` (dimensions: NxJ) and store the result in `inc` (dimensions: NxJ). The second loop converts the complex matrix `out2` (dimensions: NxJ) into amplitude and phase parts and stores it consecutively in `t` (dimensions Nx2J). `inc`, `out1`, `out1`, and `B` are all of type `fftw_complex` (2 `double`)  while `t` is a float.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N * J; i++)
{
    k = i % N;
    inc[i][REAL] = out1[k][REAL] * B[i][REAL] - out1[k][IMAG] * B[i][IMAG];
    inc[i][IMAG] = out1[k][REAL] * B[i][IMAG] + out1[k][IMAG] * B[i][REAL];
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < N * J; i++)
{
    t[i]         = (float) sqrt(out2[i][REAL] * out2[i][REAL] 
                             +  out2[i][IMAG] * out2[i][IMAG]);
    t[N * J + i] = (float) atan2(out2[i][IMAG], out2[i][REAL]);
}
```

When compiled with: `-Ofast -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed
-mavx2 -msse4`, the output for loop 1 is:

```
note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _50 = *_49[0];
note: bad data references.
note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
note: not consecutive access _50 = *_49[0];
note: Build SLP failed: unrolling required in basic block SLP
note: not consecutive access _50 = *_49[0];
note: Build SLP failed: unvectorizable statement _50 = *_49[0];
note: Build SLP failed: different interleaving chains in one node _60 = *_49[0];
```

and the output for loop 2 is:

```
note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *_70 and *_84
note: vector alignment may not be reachable
note: virtual phi. skip.
note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
note: not ssa-name.
note: use not simple.
note: no array mode for V4DF[2]
note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
note: not ssa-name.
note: use not simple.
note: no array mode for V4DF[2]
note: function is not vectorizable.
note: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _85 = atan2 (_75, _73);
note: bad operation or unsupported loop bound.
note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *_70 and *_84
note: vector alignment may not be reachable
note: virtual phi. skip.
note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
note: not ssa-name.
note: use not simple.
note: no array mode for V2DF[2]
note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
note: not ssa-name.
note: use not simple.
note: no array mode for V2DF[2]
note: function is not vectorizable.
note: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _85 = atan2 (_75, _73);
note: bad operation or unsupported loop bound.
note: not vectorized: no grouped stores in basic block.
```

I have observed that these loops are the bottlenecks in my code. How do I vectorize them?

Comment: I had the error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted..." I was trying to locate it by using quotes as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251183/cannot-figure-why-am-getting-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-prop), hoping to get the offending line number, but it got posted instead. I decided to let it be since apart from the quote, the formatting is fine. Please let me know if it is unacceptable.

Comment: The dimensions are (JxN) and (2JxN) rather than (NxJ) and (Nx2J) but I can't edit the post without the above error.

Comment: You should avoid `%` in the `for` loops. The indexes of arrays should increase constantly.

Comment: @mch Not sure how I'd do that here, I need to index vector `out1` only till N while matrices `inc` and `B` need to be indexed till NxJ.

Comment: You might benefit from making `k` a local within the loop body; does it help to split the second into two loops that can be vectorised independently?

Comment: something like http://ideone.com/cjpq2a

Comment: better: http://ideone.com/qENTUP

Comment: Like @mch's suggestion, I went for two nested loops, one running till J and the other till N and then did some pointer arithmetic, i * N + j for the "absolute" reference and just "j" for the index till N. I have some mixed signals, while -fopt-info-vec-missed [tells](https://gist.github.com/sgrax/62ec8a1dae5d70d27943a18922a4a77e) me it didn't work out, -fopt-info-vec-optimized [tells](https://gist.github.com/sgrax/feb419b4a079d92132d33028fbbb9132) me it managed to vectorize the inner loop.  (Line 131 is the outer `J` loop and 133 is the inner `N` loop.

Comment: @TobySpeight I split loop 2 into the amplitude and phase parts. The amplitude part now gets vectorized but not the phase part. I guess it's because the left side of the assignment indexes [N * J + i] while the right side indexes just [i]. Any suggestions on how to get around that?

Comment: Er, `float *const p = t + N*J;` perhaps?  Then you'd be assigning to `t[i]` and to `p[i]`.  That's just guesswork, though - I'll try to knock up a [mcve] to reproduce your results.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work out. One of the messages is: `not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _99 = atan2 (_98, _97);`. Is `atan2` inherently incompatible with SIMD?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if either of the loops created by splitting loop 2 are vectorized. While `-fopt-info-vec-optimized` says that the amplitude loop at (line 144) succeeded, [this](https://gist.github.com/sgrax/5e47b1345d1ff229891ef5fb413478f0) is what I have from `-fopt-info-vec-missed` (149 is the phase loop).

Answer (score 1):

My compilable version of the code is

```
#include <math.h>

typedef double complex[2];
static const int REAL = 0;
static const int IMAG = 1;

void loop1(int N, int J, const complex B[], const complex out1[], complex inc[])
{
    const int NJ = N * J;
    for (int i = 0; i < NJ; ++i) {
        const int k = i % N;
        inc[i][IMAG] = out1[k][REAL] * B[i][IMAG] + out1[k][IMAG] * B[i][REAL];
        inc[i][REAL] = out1[k][REAL] * B[i][REAL] - out1[k][IMAG] * B[i][IMAG];
    }
}

void loop2(int N, int J, float t[], const complex out2[])
{
    const int NJ = N * J;
    float *const p = t + NJ;
    for (int i = 0; i < NJ; ++i) {
        /*t[i] = (float) hypot(out2[i][REAL], out2[i][IMAG]);*/
        t[i] = (float) sqrt(out2[i][REAL] * out2[i][REAL] + out2[i][IMAG] * out2[i][IMAG]);
        p[i] = (float) atan2(out2[i][IMAG], out2[i][REAL]);
    }
}
```

For the first loop, I get:

```
42504487.c:10:5: note: not vectorized: not suitable for gather load _16 = *_15[0];
42504487.c:10:5: note: bad data references.
42504487.c:10:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
42504487.c:15:1: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
42504487.c:10:5: note: Two or more load stmts share the same dr.
42504487.c:10:5: note: Two or more load stmts share the same dr.
42504487.c:10:5: note: Build SLP failed: unrolling required in basic block SLP
42504487.c:10:5: note: Two or more load stmts share the same dr.
42504487.c:10:5: note: Two or more load stmts share the same dr.
42504487.c:10:5: note: can't determine dependence between *_11[1] and *_15[1]
```

For the second loop, I get:

```
42504487.c:21:5: note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *_13 and *_25
42504487.c:21:5: note: vector alignment may not be reachable
42504487.c:21:5: note: virtual phi. skip.
42504487.c:21:5: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
42504487.c:21:5: note: not ssa-name.
42504487.c:21:5: note: use not simple.
42504487.c:21:5: note: no array mode for V4DF[2]
42504487.c:21:5: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
42504487.c:21:5: note: not ssa-name.
42504487.c:21:5: note: use not simple.
42504487.c:21:5: note: no array mode for V4DF[2]
42504487.c:21:5: note: function is not vectorizable.
42504487.c:21:5: note: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _26 = atan2 (_19, _17);
42504487.c:21:5: note: bad operation or unsupported loop bound.
42504487.c:21:5: note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *_13 and *_25
42504487.c:21:5: note: vector alignment may not be reachable
42504487.c:21:5: note: virtual phi. skip.
42504487.c:21:5: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
42504487.c:21:5: note: not ssa-name.
42504487.c:21:5: note: use not simple.
42504487.c:21:5: note: no array mode for V2DF[2]
42504487.c:21:5: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
42504487.c:21:5: note: not ssa-name.
42504487.c:21:5: note: use not simple.
42504487.c:21:5: note: no array mode for V2DF[2]
42504487.c:21:5: note: function is not vectorizable.
42504487.c:21:5: note: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _26 = atan2 (_19, _17);
42504487.c:21:5: note: bad operation or unsupported loop bound.
42504487.c:21:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
42504487.c:26:1: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
42504487.c:21:5: note: not vectorized: no grouped stores in basic block.
```

Here, we have "no array mode for V4DF[2]" and "no array mode for V2DF[2]", suggesting we don't have suitable types for the vectorisation.

Also, "relevant stmt not supported: atan2" tells us that there isn't a vector implementation of `atan2`.

At this point, if there are enough cores available, I'd look to OpenMP instead, perhaps using `-floop-parallelize-all`.

Comment: You have REAL and IMAg both equal 0, where IMAG should equal 1. That makes big difference.

Comment: Thanks, @Anty (that's why a [mcve] in the question is so important).  Fix imminent, when I have new diagnostics to incorporate.

Comment: Now edited.  I tried adding `restrict` qualifiers to `B`, `inc`, `out1`, `out2`, `t` and `p` but still didn't manage to vectorize the code.

Comment: Because it won't vectorize in this form - I'll look at it how to fix it when I'm home.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have split loops for amplitude and phase, and have the error `no array mode for V2DF[2]` and `no array mode for V4DF[2]` but at the same time, `-fopt-info-vec-optimized` tells me that the amplitude loop was vectorized. For the complex multiplication loop, it tells me that the inner loop was vectorize but at the same time, I have `-fopt-info-vec-missed` telling me _thrice_ that it was not vectorized, `not enough data-refs in block`. How can we be sure whether it's actually vectorizing or not?